# How to convert local date to UTC in Mirth?

Tags: date, utc, date-conversion, mirth

In Mirth I receive a local datetime string (`201801011000`) which I need to convert to UTC. I soon found out using the classic js `new Date()` doesn't work well.

This for example:

```
var d = new Date("2018-01-01 10:00");
logger.info(d.toString());
```

gives me an `Invalid Date`.

So after some more searching I found I can do this:

```
var d = DateUtil.getDate("yyyyMMddHHmm", "201801011000");
```

and from here I'm stuck. I don't know how I can convert this to UTC. Local server timezone is assumed which is enough for now, but in the future I also need to set a specific non-local timezone.

I tried to get the methods I can use with  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(d)`, but that gives me the helpfull `TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object`

I also tried looking up the Java docs for DateUtil and tried some methods from that, but nothing worked.

How can I convert datestring from local time to UTC?

Comment: According to [these docs](http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.1.0/user-api/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/DateUtil.html), it looks like this is Java and it returns a `java.util.Date` object?  If so, that question has been answered many times already. I'm a bit confused because I don't know Mirth and you mentioned "classic js" - so is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: I can not answer the question, but as a background - it's kind of both. :) Mirth uses Rhino JavaScript engine for it's scripting, which means you write JS code and have access to all Java classes in the classpath. It can and does get confusing with issues like "is it a JavaScript or Java String object I'm handling here?!". I can only assume, that it's similar with date and time manipulations.

Comment: @TarmoR That sounds hellish

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: You should use the latest java classes given from java8 for conversion.I have added my answer for your explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after messing around with this for about two full days I finally found a solution. In the end I had to tap into Java, but since I couldn't import any java dependencies I had to use their direct class path (e.g.: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`).

In the end this is what worked for me:

```
var datestr = "201207011000".slice(0, 12);  // This is just a datetime string to test with

var formatter_hl7 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
formatter_hl7.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
var formatter_utc = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
formatter_utc.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

var date_in_utc = formatter_utc.format(formatter_hl7.parse(date_str));
```

Regardless, I wish you all a beautiful day!

Comment: Whoever downvoted this; why did you downvote it? Please explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps the downvote is because you are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the excellent *java.time* classes.

Comment: Just suggestion: not to use old java classes for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- Do not use `DateUtil` whatever that is. (Perhaps Apache DateUtils library?)
- Do not use terrible old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`.
- Use the modern industry-leading *java.time* classes.

Code for parsing a string lacking an offset, then assigning an offset of zero for UTC itself.

```
LocalDateTime                // Represents a date and a time-of-day but without any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. NOT a moment, NOT a point on the timeline.
.parse( 
    "201801011000" ,
     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" )
)  
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Assign an offset-from-UTC. Do this only if you are CERTAIN this offset was originally intended for this input but was unfortunately omitted from the text. Returns an `OffsetDateTime`.
.toInstant()                 // Extract an `Instant` from the `OffsetDateTime`. Basically the same thing. But `Instant` is always in UTC by definition, so this type is more appropriate if your intention is to work only in UTC. On the other hand, `Instant` is a basic class, and `OffsetDateTime` is more flexible such as various formatting patterns when generating `String` object to represent its value.
```

## Using *java.time*

The modern approach in Java uses the *java.time* classes. This industry-leading framework supplanted the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Parse your input string. Define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" ) ;
String input = "201801011000" ;
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because your input lacks an indicator for time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Lacking a zone or offset means this does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Instead, this represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

### `OffsetDateTime`

If you know for certain that this date and time-of-day were intended to represent a moment in UTC, apply the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` to get an `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Your Question is vague. It sounds like you might know of an specific time zone intended for this input. If so, assign a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Understand that an offset-from-UTC is but a mere number of hours, minutes, and seconds. Nothing more, nothing less. In contrast, a time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a certain region.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

### `Instant`

A quick way to adjust back into UTC is to extract a `Instant` object. An `Instant` is always in UTC.

```
Instant instan = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

### ISO 8601

Tip: Instead of using custom format for exchanging date-time values as text, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The standard formats are practical, easy to parse by machine, easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime::toString` method wisely extends the standard to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-07-23T16:18:54Z" ) ;  // `Z` on the end means UTC, pronounced “Zulu”. 
String output = instant.toString() ;  // 2018-07-23T16:18:54Z
```

And always include the offset and time zone in your string. Omitting the offset/zone for a moment is like omitting the currency for a price: All you have left is an ambiguous number worth nothing. Actually, worse than nothing as it can cause all sorts of confusion and errors.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: [DateUtil](http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.0.0/user-api/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/DateUtil.html) belongs to mirth's flavor of java. Its name couldn't be more spot on: a date utility class lacking in utility.

Answer (score 0):

In my project have function for convert `datestring` local time to UTC,

```
function getDateInUTC(dateString) {
    return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET")).parse(dateString));
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "format" of undefined`. Any idea?

Comment: please import `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest classes [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) provided from Java8.

Steps are as follows:

**Step-1.** Parse `String` to `LocalDateTime`

**Step-2.** Convert `LocalDateTime` to the `ZonedDateTime` and then we can convert between different `timezone`.

**Hope this help:**

**In Mirth you can write as:**

```
String str = "201207011000"; 
var date_in_utc =java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                .format(java.time.ZonedDateTime.of(java.time.LocalDateTime
                .parse(str,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm")),java.time.ZoneId.of("CET"))
                .withZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

**Full Snippet:**

```
ZoneId cet = ZoneId.of("CET");
String str = "201207011000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm");
LocalDateTime localtDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
ZonedDateTime dateAndTimeInCET = ZonedDateTime.of(localtDateAndTime, cet );
System.out.println("Current date and time in a CET timezone : " + dateAndTimeInCET);
ZonedDateTime utcDate = dateAndTimeInCET.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println("Current date and time in UTC : " + utcDate);
System.out.println("Current date and time in UTC : " + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(utcDate));
```

Answer (score -2):

Give this a shout

```
var d = DateUtil.getDate("yyyyMMddHHmm", "201801011000");
var utcD = new Date(d).toISOString();
```

edit: Info on .toISOString() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Hey Boosh. Sorry for the late reply. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately just get `RangeError: Date is invalid.` for the second line. I logged `d`, and that is an object correctly pointing to the first of jan 2018 at 10 o' clock. No idea why `Date` cannot be used. Any other ideas?